# SQL UNION ORDER BY DATE Latest to Oldest

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, union

How should i play this query to order by date_scheduled From Latest to oldest thanks in advance.

```
$query = "(SELECT ref_num, event_type, time_scheduled, date_scheduled, date_apply as a, time_apply as t, m_lname as b, m_fname as c, f_fname as d, `read` as r,  'wedding' as type FROM wedding) 
           UNION
           (SELECT ref_num, event_type, time_scheduled, date_scheduled, date_apply as a, time_apply as t, c_lname as b, c_fname as c, c_mname as d, `read` as r, 'baptism' as type FROM baptism) 
           ORDER BY date_scheduled DESC LIMIT 15
           ";
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score -1):

Try this.....

```
$query = "SELECT ref_num, event_type, time_scheduled, date_scheduled, a, t, b, c, d, r, type from (SELECT ref_num, event_type, time_scheduled, date_scheduled, date_apply as a, time_apply as t, m_lname as b, m_fname as c, f_fname as d, `read` as r,  'wedding' as type FROM wedding) 
           UNION
           (SELECT ref_num, event_type, time_scheduled, date_scheduled, date_apply as a, time_apply as t, c_lname as b, c_fname as c, c_mname as d, `read` as r, 'baptism' as type FROM baptism) as tmp
           ORDER BY date_scheduled DESC LIMIT 15
           ";
```

Comment: I don't think this is any different from their existing query, is it?